# Are there any learning paths for LAMP development?

Tags: linux, magento, lamp

I got hired on as a junior developer at a company that does some e-commerce work. They are sending me to different training courses for Linux Fundamentals, Linux System Administration, and then to a Magento Bootcamp. With that being said I am hoping to be proactive about my training and how soak in as much as I can.

I was looking at Lynda, Pluralsight, TheOdinProject as well as many other sites and there isn't really an online learning path that suits the LAMP stack. Does anyone have recommendations? Maybe I should be looking at individual courses rather than the stack itself? If that is the case, which courses?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAMP is Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP. To learn this stack you should look for individual courses. Although they all go hand-in-hand, you will need to focus on them individually until you're working in an environment which uses the full stack (i.e. Magento).

I suggest learning these things: How to install the LAMP stack, basic linux terminal commands, basic MySQL commands and using MySQL from the command line, understanding what Apache is/does, understanding what MVC pattern is (Model, View, Controller) and also diving into the basics of PHP and Object-Oriented Programming methodology.

Magento is a very complex application with a lot of moving parts. Understanding LAMP is very different from understanding Magento and how to develop in it. Magento uses all these elements but is a deep framework which has its own way of doing things. I suggest learning the basics and have a general understanding of the LAMP components, this will help you a lot when you go to the Magento training.

I hope this was helpful!